# How to get access to root view in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I get the access to root view like in Java, for example:

I know using kotlin extensions we do not need to use findViewById anymore, but I do not know how to handle it. Thank you for any help.

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup =
                (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        if (viewGroup instanceof ConstraintLayout) {
         // some logic code
}
```

Comment: we don't need to use findViewById  if you are using kotlin synthetic , but that does not mean you can't use it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also access `rootView` like this

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

So in `koltin`

```
val rootView = window.decorView.rootView
```

Comment: Hi Prihtvi, thanx for your quick response. Why I am unable to use window in Fragment? Or I am missing some import?

Comment: In the case of Fragment use `requireActivity().window`. `window` is part of activity so you need to get the activity instance first

Answer (score 0):

Just place an id on the root and than access it just like you access other `Views`. Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        **android:id="@+id/mRootView"**
        android:background="#000000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

And than in MainActivity (or WhateverActivity/Fragment):

```
val rootView = mRootView
```

Answer (score 0):

In an **Activity**, you can use:

```
val rootLayout =  this.window.decorView.rootView
```

but if you are going to use it in a **class**, pass the target activity

```
val rootLayout = activity.window.decorView.rootView
```